# Why doesn't build of net-snmp 5.7.2. provide /etc/rc.d/init.d/snmptrapd?

Tags: rhel, rpm, snmp

I am packaging an RPM for RHEL6, built from net-snmp-5.7.2.tar.gz.  I see that the file `/etc/rc.d/init.d/snmpd` gets created and packaged but I do not see the init file for `/etc/rc.d/init.d/snmptrapd`.  Is snmptrapd depreciated? I did I forget pass the right switch to `./configure` ?

Thanks

Comment: To be able to answer that, we'd have to see at least the SPEC file you are using. Did you start with the respective RHEL source RPM?

Comment: Ah thanks for the hint.  The spec file does set up `snmpd` and I found the `snmptrapd` init file in the `dist` directory.  I is called `snmptrapd-init.d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the `snmptrapd` init file in the `dist` directory. It is called `snmptrapd-init.d`